# Convert nvarchar to DateTime in this format 'May 21 2013 9:45AM'

Tags: t-sql, datetime

I have a text field that is in this format `May 21 2013  9:45AM`.  How would I convert that to `datetime`?  I tried the following

```
UPDATE WaterRevLienInfo
SET    LienDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), LienDate), 101)
```

It works as a select and comes out like `2013-05-21 09:45:00.000` but not as an update.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be "round tripping" the the `LienDate` field by casting it to a `varchar` and then back to a `datetime`. I'm not sure what this is accomplishing.

However, if you have a text value in the format you specified (which is, by default, how SQL represents `datetime` fields when casted to a `varchar`), you can just do a straight convert:

```
DECLARE @DateText varchar(30) = 'May 21 2013 9:45AM';

UPDATE WaterRevLienInfo
    -- Convert the DateText string value for storage in a datetime field.
SET LienDate = CONVERT(datetime, @DateText);
```

This should also work with other fields in the same table.

```
UPDATE WaterRevLienInfo
SET LienDate = CONVERT(datetime, DateTextField);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime` hasn't any format it just a data. The presentation must care about the format.